# Is there a way to customize UITableView's separator line graphics?

Tags: uitableview, graphics, separator

I'm finding customizing UITableView's separator line graphics.
It's basically a single line and it can be hidden. But I cannot know how to draw separator with my own custom graphics or image. Is there a regular way to do this?
Or do I have to draw all myself and manage them manually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple way is hide the separator and embed your own separator in the cell's background image.

---

If you need to draw your own separator, you need to override `-[UITableView _drawExtraSeparator:]` or `-[UITableViewCell _drawSeparatorInRect:]` or `-[_UITableViewSeparatorView drawRect:]`. These are all *undocumented* so don't think about using them in the AppStore.

Comment: If regular way is undocumented (so prohibited) I should choose the first way you mentioned. Thanks for in-depth answer!